# Can a Mac OSX app access CloudKit without being on the Mac App Store?

Tags: cloudkit

Being on the Mac App Store is a requirement to access iCloud.

Will the same apply to accessing CloudKit?

The scenario is to have an Mac OSX application share data with an iOS counterpart via CloudKit.

According to this article - http://9to5mac.com/2014/06/05/icloud-drive-enables-non-mac-app-store-apps-to-use-icloud-document-storage/ - you do not but I'm seeking confirmation from any developer who has actually managed to do it.

Comment: could you please explain the scenario also

Comment: sounds like since you have to use icloud, that its required. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/DesigningforCloudKit/DesigningforCloudKit.html

Comment: Not according to this article:http://9to5mac.com/2014/06/05/icloud-drive-enables-non-mac-app-store-apps-to-use-icloud-document-storage/

Answer (score 8):

This changed for Mac apps according to this WWDC video (see at minute 6:00):

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/226/?time=359

It's now available outside of the mac app store.

Answer (score 5):

The article that you link to does not relate to CloudKit, and in fact does not even mention CloudKit. CloudKit is not iCloud.

What the article says (which is probably true) is that apps distributed outside the app store can access iCloud Drive. This is a new feature yet to be officially released which will apparently be something like Dropbox. Apps will probably be able to read/write files in iCloud Drive just like in any other folder on a Mac.

CloudKit is an entirely separate system with a web service-style API for reading and writing structured data using Apple's servers. It's not available to apps outside of the app store, because those APIs won't work unless the app has the appropriate capabilities via Apple's app provisioning process.

Comment: Thanks, Tom, it was the bit about "iCloud documents" that put me on the wrong track.

Answer (score 1):

Since CloudKit is released in iOS 8 now, the question itself is valid though.

Quoting from the documentation:

> CloudKit is an app service available only to apps distributed through the App Store and Mac App Store